# Arduino Nano - LED - MPR121 - HC_06BT PCB check

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, bluetooth, led-strip

I´m working on a multi-touch Bluetooth device with integrated LEDs for a multimedia-installation. Because I'm new in PCB design and electronics in general, I would like to know if this schematic/PCB makes sense.

[image: PCB Front]

[image: PCB Back]

[image: schematic]

Answer (score 0):

Your schematics seems good.

Looking at your PCB design, it's not so clear in the picture.
Did you use ground plane on the bottom of the PCB?

Touch sensing is sensitive for capacitance.
Thus, you'd better not to put ground plane near or under the routing to your 12-pin connector. Anyhow, current design might work, but if you read the touch sensor datasheet or design guidelines, you can know how more.

Comment: Yes, I used the ground plane in the hole PCB, top and bottom.